# Unable to deduce two constrained types are the same

Tags: haskell

I have a couple of classes that form part of a wider hierarchy and I'm trying to implement them on `DepTag`:

```
class StanfordType a where
  text :: a -> Text

class StanfordType a => Dep a where
  relation :: (StanfordType b) => a -> b

data DepTag a b where
  DepTag :: (StanfordType a) => Text -> a -> DepTag Text a

instance StanfordType (DepTag a b) where 
  text (DepTag s _) = s

instance Dep (DepTag a b) where 
  relation (DepTag _ r) = r
```

When I try to compile this, I'm thrown the following error:

```
• Could not deduce: b ~ b1
  from the context: (a ~ Text, N.StanfordType b)
    bound by a pattern with constructor:
               DepTag :: forall b. N.StanfordType b => Text -> b -> DepTag Text b,
             in an equation for ‘relation’
    at src/NLP/Data.hs:17:45-54
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the instance declaration at src/NLP/Data.hs:17:10
  ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      relation :: forall b1. N.StanfordType b1 => DepTag a b -> b1
    at src/NLP/Data.hs:17:35
• In the expression: r
  In an equation for ‘relation’: relation (DepTag _ r) = r
  In the instance declaration for ‘N.Dep (DepTag a b)’
• Relevant bindings include
    r :: b (bound at src/NLP/Data.hs:17:54)
    relation :: DepTag a b -> b1 (bound at src/NLP/Data.hs:17:35)
```

I can't work out why the compiler can't see that both `r` in `relation` (Dep) and `b` in the type signature of `relation` are the same. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible to implement `relation`. StanfordType is basically just `Show` but with `Text` and thus `relation` is pretty much `(Dep a, Show b) => a -> b`. How do you want to whip up any `Show t => t` value? This seems practically impossible. Just like implementing a (total) function `a -> b`.

Comment: The compiler can't work out that they are the same, because they aren't. The type variable in the definition of `Dep` is not the same as the `b` in the definition of `DepTag`.

Comment: @jpath I'm definitely missing something because I don't understand how they are not the same? `DepTag` has two parameters, the second I thought was constrained to be a member of `StanfordType`. The function `relation` also returns a value that is constrained to be a member of `StanfordType`. What am I missing?

Comment: The `b` can be *any* Member of Stanford type. So if I make a type `Foo` and make it a member of `StandfordType`. Then `relation` has to be able to whip up `Foo`s, because `relation :: Dep a => a -> Foo` is a valid instantiation of `relation`. Can you give me a valid value of `Foo`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm still not quite following though. If I decide to implement 1000 members of `StanfordType`, I don't understand how they affect `relation`. So long as `relation` has the ability to return at least one of those 1000 members of `StanfordType`, isn't that alright?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't work out why the compiler can't see that both r in relation (Dep) and b in the type signature of relation are the same.

The problem is that they are not the same. The problem here is, that `relation :: (Dep a, StanfordType b) => a -> b` has to be able to return every valid `b`. So while your understanding of the type signature is that you can return any `b` that you (the writer of `relation`) want it actually means, that you have to return any `b` that I (the caller of `relation`) want. We can make this difference explicit like this (the second variant is not actual Haskell syntax and the first is not standard Haskell):

```
relation :: forall b. (Dep a, StanfordType b) => a -> b -- Actual meaning
relation :: exists b. (Dep a, StanfordType b) => a -> b -- Your interpretation
```

So if make a type `Foo`, that is an instance of `StanfordType`:

```
newtype Foo = Foo | Bar
instance StanfordType Foo where
   text = pack "FooBar"
```

you can now verify with GHCi, that resolution actually has to be able to return values of type `Foo`:

```
 > :t resolution :: Dep a => a -> Foo
 resolution :: Dep a => a -> Foo :: Dep a => a -> Foo
```

Of course it is impossible to create values of any unknown type with a `StanfordType` instance. Especially because literally every type can have a `StanfordType` instance.

We can actually express the second type using an existential:

```
data ExtStanfordType where
   EST :: StanfordType a => a -> ExtStanfordType

class StanfordType a => Dep a where
    relation :: a -> ExtStanfordType

instance Dep (DepTag a b) where
    relation = (DepTag _ r) = EST r
```

Now resolution can return any `StanfordType` wrapped up in an `ExtStanfordType`. You can then use `text` like this:

```
 textExt :: ExtStanfordType -> Text
 textExt (EST b) = text b
```

See also: [Existential type - Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type)

Comment: I see, perfect - this really helped. Turns out I need to fundamentally rethink this :)

Comment: I never recommend the classic existential quantification syntax to beginners. GADT syntax, which the OP clearly knows already, is both clearer and more powerful.

Comment: @dfeuer How about you make an edit? I'm not familiar with GADTs.

Comment: GADTs basically just let you give an explicit type signature to each constructor, as long as each of them ultimately produces a value of a type whose type constructor is the one being defined. This is ultimately very powerful, since the result can serve as type evidence.

Comment: @dfeuer I see. Thank you.