# why doesn't the compiler accept returning Int8 as "Real c"?

Tags: haskell, numbers

I have this example code :

```
module Main where

import Data.Int
import Data.Text

data JavaValue = JavaString Text
              | JavaByte Int8
              | JavaShort Int16
              | JavaInt Int32
              | JavaLong Int64
              | JavaFloat Float
              | JavaDouble Double
              | JavaChar Char
              | JavaBool Bool
              | ArrayValue [JavaValue]
              | JavaNull deriving (Eq)

getnumberfromvalue :: Real c => JavaValue -> Maybe c
getnumberfromvalue (JavaByte n) =Just n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaShort n) =Just n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaInt n) =Just n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaLong n) =Just n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaFloat n) =Just n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaDouble n) =Just n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaChar n) =Just $ fromEnum n
getnumberfromvalue _ = Nothing
```

This code doesn't compile with this error :

> test.hs:25:34: error:
>
> ```
> • Couldn't match type ‘c’ with ‘Int’
>   ‘c’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>     the type signature for:
>       getnumberfromvalue :: forall c. Real c => JavaValue -> Maybe c
>     at test.hs:18:23
>   Expected type: Maybe c
>     Actual type: Maybe Int
> • In the expression: Just $ fromEnum n
>   In an equation for ‘getnumberfromvalue’:
>       getnumberfromvalue (JavaChar n) = Just $ fromEnum n
> • Relevant bindings include
>     getnumberfromvalue :: JavaValue -> Maybe c (bound at test.hs:19:1)
> ```

I don't understand why, since `Int(8,16,32,64)`and `Float` and `Double` all are `Real` why does it say it can't match `Int` with `c` ?!!

The above code is just a small part of a java compiler I'm building for university project, `getnumberfromvalue` is just a utility function, `JavaValue` is to represent a java literal.

I know about `fromIntegral` and `realToFrac` and I don't think I can use them here.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508145/unable-to-deduce-two-constrained-types-are-the-same) question but the answer uses GADT and ExistentialQuantification seems to be only for types, I don't think I want to use it for this simple problem, even without GADT isn't there a way that doesn't involve defining a trivial data type ? .

Comment: This is not how polymorphism works in Haskell.  Type classes aren't subtyping. Type variables are chosen by the *caller* of a function, not the function itself. Is there some question that covers this really well already?

Comment: Edit: totally wrong statement preserved for posterity follows - Oh and, for what it's worth, `Int` and `Word` types are not instances of `Real`.

Comment: @Carl Yes they are.

Comment: @jpath Well shoot.  I was thinking of the wrong class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to deduce two constrained types are the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508145/unable-to-deduce-two-constrained-types-are-the-same)

Comment: @jpath see my edit

Comment: Relevant: [*How to comfortably deal with the type system on Haskell?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40432690/2751851)

Comment: @Carl I don't think it's totally wrong. The point about tyvars chosen by the caller and not by the function/callee is correct, and is the crux of this problem. And I agree that we need a reference question for this -- it's being asked again and again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're aiming to express is an *existential type*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data SomeReal where
  SomeReal :: Real c => c -> SomeReal

getnumberfromvalue :: JavaValue -> Maybe SomeReal
getnumberfromvalue (JavaByte n) = Just $ SomeReal n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaShort n) = Just $ SomeReal n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaInt n) = Just $ SomeReal n
...
```

This is then basically equivalent to what an OO language would mean by a signature like `Real getNumberFromValue (JavaValue v) {...}`: the function returns a number of *some type*, the caller doesn't know what type it will be (just that it's in the `Real` class).

But why would you want that? There's not much you can do with a number of unknown type, you can't even add it or compare to other numbers because the types may be different. The only thing you *can* do, thanks to `Real` specifically, is *convert* the number to one with concrete type `Rational` (which is thought of as a “supertype of all real<sup>†</sup> number types”). Ok, but then you might as well do so right upfront, no need to wrap in in an existential:

```
getnumberfromvalue :: JavaValue -> Maybe Rational
getnumberfromvalue (JavaByte n) = Just $ toRational n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaShort n) = Just $ toRational n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaInt n) = Just $ toRational n
...
```

What a standard polymorphic Haskell signature like `Real c => JavaValue -> Maybe c` means is quite different and much more useful than existential types: it means the caller gets to choose what number type to use. This can be a fixed type that's shared across many functions, eliminating any need for conversions in between while retaining the flexibility of a dynamic language. It's more similar to C++ templates than to generic covariant OO polymorphism.
But of course that means you'll have to settle on a particular type before you start any computations, you can't just pass *numbers of unknown type* around (that would incur a lot of runtime overhead, which is basically the reason why Ruby and Python are slow and Java has non-object types like `int`).

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>IMO this is silly, since [real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) are verily in general *not* rational. The method of `Real a` should arguably be `toCauchySeq :: a -> [(Rational, Rational)]` instead. (I reckon you wouldn't prefer that, though...)</sub>

Comment: Why insult existential types? They can be quite useful indeed! There's one at the heart of the `foldl` package (related closely to the one in `Coyoneda`), and they're also important for type-aligned sequences (for "reflection without remorse"), and so on. Of course, they have no place in this particular function, but one could imagine a somewhat similar situation where they would make sense, involving multiple related numbers and functions all wrapped up in an existential.

Comment: Did I insult existentials? I just said parametric polymorphism is more useful than they are. Yes, existentials are also useful for _some_ speciality applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
getnumberfromvalue :: Fractional f => JavaValue -> Maybe f
getnumberfromvalue (JavaByte n) = Just . realToFrac $ n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaShort n) = Just . realToFrac $ n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaInt n) = Just . realToFrac $ n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaLong n) = Just . realToFrac $ n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaFloat n) = Just . realToFrac $ n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaDouble n) = Just . realToFrac $ n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaChar n) = Just . realToFrac . fromEnum $ n
getnumberfromvalue _ = Nothing
```

or like this:

```
getnumberfromvalue :: (Num a, Typeable a) => JavaValue -> Maybe a
getnumberfromvalue (JavaByte n) = Just . fromIntegral $ n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaShort n) = Just . fromIntegral $ n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaInt n) = Just . fromIntegral $ n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaLong n) = Just . fromIntegral $ n
getnumberfromvalue (JavaFloat n) = cast n <|> cast (realToFrac n :: Double)
getnumberfromvalue (JavaDouble n) = cast n <|> cast (realToFrac n :: Float)
getnumberfromvalue (JavaChar n) = Just . fromIntegral . fromEnum $ n
getnumberfromvalue _ = Nothing
```